# OpenGL - Adding a second shader attribute causes a blank screen

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

Seasons greetings everyone!

I'm trying to write a generic `DrawPolygon()` function that will take a number of sides, position, colour and size, and render an n-sided regular polygon. Can someone please tell me what's wrong with the following code?

```
void drawPolygon(GLuint& vao, GLuint& vbo, GLfloat x,
    GLfloat y, GLfloat radius, GLint numSides) {
    auto numVertices = numSides + 2;
    auto twoPi = 2.0f * M_PI;
    auto vertexData = new GLfloat[numVertices * 5];

    for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
        vertexData[i * 5] = x + (radius *
            cos(i * twoPi / numSides));
        vertexData[i * 5 + 1] = y + (radius *
            sin(i * twoPi / numSides));
        vertexData[i * 5 + 2] = 0.0f;  // Colour data: red
        vertexData[i * 5 + 3] = 1.0f;  // Colour data: green
        vertexData[i * 5 + 4] = 0.0f;  // Colour data: blue
    }

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numVertices * sizeof(
        GLfloat) * 5, vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
        5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 *
        sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(2 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, numVertices);
    auto error = glGetError();  // returns 0, i.e. no error

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    delete[] vertexData;
}
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec2 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColour;

uniform mat4 projection;

out vec3 fColour;

void main() {
    gl_Position = projection * vec4(
        aPos.x, aPos.y, 0.0, 1.0); 
    fColour = aColour;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 fColour;
out vec4 FragColor;

void main() {
    FragColor = vec4(fColour, 1.0);   
}
```

As you can see, I've hard-coded the colour values for now, but intend to pass them in as a `vec3` once I get it working. At the moment it just gives me a plain black screen :S Removing the second attribute and using a `uniform` instead works, but I'd like to know why the given code doesn't. MTIA!

Comment: Everything looks good to me… have you checked you've glUseProgram'd the right program before drawing?

Comment: Many thanks @Andrea, that was the problem! Kind of...see my answer for details. But I still think you deserve the rep, so if you post a proper answer I'll accept it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The code posted isn't setting the projection uniform -- Maybe that's being done somewhere else, but it's not clear if that's the case here.

Comment: Yep it's being done elsewhere. Thanks anyway for trying to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

OK the weirdest thing just happened: after reading @Andrea's comment above...

> Everything looks good to me… have you checked you've glUseProgram'd the right program before drawing?

...I decided to double-check, since I hadn't actually thought of that possibility. I've only been teaching myself about OpenGL from online tutorials, and only for a few days. So I thought it was quite possible that I **had indeed** made such a rookie error.

So I opened up the project in VS 2019 for the first time since posting this question, added an **explicit** call to my `Shader` wrapper class' `Use()` method instead of relying on an implicit one (see [here](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer.php?code=in-practice/breakout/shader) for details) and guess what? Just like magic, I got a green circle in the middle of the screen!

That part isn't so weird; as I said before it's quite possible that I misread Joey's tutorial linked above or miscopied the code. But here's the kicker: after returning the code to the original non-working version (pasted verbatim from this question), **it still works!!**

Anyway problem solved I guess...I hate it when a bug magically fixes itself like this; you can't help but think that it will suddenly reappear later down the track. But for now I'm having a "randomly-coloured polygon" party, and loving it!

Comment: Suspicious. Either your code is actually subtly different from before, or this is some kind of undefined behaviour?

Comment: @Andrea Yeah not sure, although I think me not noticing some crucial change is much more likely than having discoved UB. Anyway it works now so that's the main thing. I'll be sure to whine about it on here if that ever changes again :P